# What is the ideal database(s) and design for chat applications?

Tags: database-design

I want to transfer real-time chat build on firebase RTDB due to scaling issues. The current system has around 5000 active users and 30000 daily messages which we expect to scale around half a million message a day. We have implemented 1-1 chat, Group chat.

What would be the ideal database(s) for us to scale the chat app well and what should be the design?

Comment: *5000 active users and 30000 daily messages* 6 mess per user per day? Yes, even text files :) *Group chat and Project Chat* Where they differs in?

Comment: It's still in beta, so we are expecting around half a million messages daily. Group and project chat is kind of similar expect of access rules and members.

Comment: *Group and project chat is kind of similar expect of access rules and members* So it is a groups which differs in their attributes only (maybe fixed members list, visibility to external users, etc.). 1-1 chat is a kind of group too. So implement group chat only, and build a system of groups.

Comment: Yes, But I am very much confused between selecting database(s). Whether to go with NoSQL or SQL and which database?

Comment: *Whether to go with NoSQL or SQL* Depends on the list of data operations and the proportion of each operation. In general SQL DBMS seems to be preferred.